# String Tokenizer - To grab ques and answer by tag

Tags: java, eclipse, stringtokenizer

I have removed the tags so the arrayList looks like this:

```
Qstore.add(new QuestionObject("Question 2?", "1", "2", "3", "4", "B", "Starts with M", "Easy", "Sport"));
Qstore.add(new QuestionObject("Question 3?", "221", "233", "443", "455", "C", "Starts with M", "Easy", "Sport"));
```

I have got my Millionaire Program to run with ArrayList but when the GUI displays the question and Answers, it mixes the question and answer list up with other arraylist

Comment: You should use an XML parser instead of a tokenizer.

Comment: @JoshM It's a normal File with just tags around it

Comment: And, to further what @m0skit0 said, XPath may be of some use here.

Comment: @m0skit0 I suggested the same thing (and then later removed my comment) because an XML parser would fail because the closing question tag is placed before all of the answers.

Comment: @JoshM That is one of the reasons why I decided to go for tokens.

Comment: XML Parser will make it easy

Comment: I would still use an XML parser. You just need to do a little more work to to figure out which answers are associated with which questions. Unless the tokenizer correctly separates the tag and the text, which is what an XML parser would do. If you need to write the parsing logic yourself to set up the tokenizer, just go with an XML parser.

Comment: Granted, you would have to do something about the input to make it well-formed otherwise XML parsers won't accept it.

Comment: @CodeChimp can I ask a quick question mate?

Comment: With XPath you could get the sibling Answers to the Question, and still use an XML parser to validate and do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @CodeChimp check bottom of the top code edited it and added new question. I have got my Millionaire Program to run with ArrayList but when the GUI displays the question and Answers, it mixes the question and answer list up with other arraylist.

Comment: I have no idea what you are doing up there.  Other than creating two instances of an object that has a very nasty and confusing constructor.  Also, if you have a new question, you should really close the existing one and open a new one.  Now all the below answers make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

For your simple case, you might create a small tag table (`String[] tab = {"A","B","C","D","ANS"}` and then see which tag is present in a line (`if (line.trim().startsWith("<"+tag[i]+">") ...`

You could then extract the text between where the beginning tag ends `"<"+tag[i]+">"` and where the end tag begins `"</"+tag[i]+">"`

Comment: @Erstwhilelll hey you there I got a question about an ArrayList

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ErstWhilelll I have got my Millionaire Program to run with ArrayList but when the GUI displays the question and Answers, it mixes the question and answer list up with other arraylist.

Comment: @ErstWhilelll Plus I have removed the tags so the arrayList looks like this:

Qstore.add(new QuestionObject("Question 2?", "1", "2", "3", "4", "B", "Starts with M", "Easy", "Sport"));

Comment: List as a separate question with your code and results

Answer (score 0):

```
    BufferedReader in;
    String pattern = ".*<Question>(.+?)</Question>.*";

    in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("fileName.txt"));

    String line = null;
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

        if (line.matches(pattern)) {
            String replacedText = line.replaceAll(pattern, "$1");
            System.out.println("replacedText: " + replacedText);
        }
    }
```

Above given code uses regex to fetch the question present within the  tags

Comment: you there? I have a quick question mate